# StructureMap Generic Ctor Named Instance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap

## Update

I *solved* this problem with the following code, but it's not the solution I'm looking for. **This is still an open bounty for a more generic solution.** If we ever have a table that isn't an `int` or `string` for the key value we'll have to add to this manually to make it work.

```
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesCommand<,>)).Use(typeof(LogDifferencesCommand<,>))
                .Ctor<ILogDifferencesLogger<int>>()
                .Named(AppSettingsManager.Get("logDifferences:Target"))
                .Ctor<string>()
                .Named(AppSettingsManager.Get("logDifferences:Target"));
```

## Original Question

I have three types of loggers, and I've defined named instances in my container for them:

```
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesAllLogger<>))
    .Named("all");
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesNLogLogger<>))
    .Named("nlog");
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesDatabaseLogger<>))
    .Named("database");
```

The `LogDifferencesCommand` receives an `ILogDifferencesLogger<>` as its only argument:

```
public LogDifferencesCommand(ILogDifferencesLogger<TKey> logDifferencesLogger)
{
    this.logDifferencesLogger = logDifferencesLogger;
}
```

How do I properly configure the `ILogDifferencesCommand<>` to grab the right *named instance* based off of an application setting? Right now I've got something like this:

```
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesCommand<,>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesCommand<,>));
```

The issue I'm having is I can't pull in the `Ctor<>` because I can't use unbound generics with that signature, so then I can't use the `Named` method off the `Ctor` for that.

For example, I could do something like this, but that wouldn't hit all possible types:

```
c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesCommand<,>)).Use(typeof(LogDifferencesCommand<,>))
    .Ctor<ILogDifferencesLogger<int>>()
    .Named(AppSettingsManager.Get("logDifferences:Target"));
```

But the problem then is I'd have to handle every `TKey` type the system uses.

## Class and Interface Definitions

```
public class LogDifferencesCommand<TModel, TKey> : ILogDifferencesCommand<TModel, TKey>
    where TModel : class, IIdModel<TKey>
{
    public LogDifferencesCommand(ILogDifferencesLogger<TKey> logDifferencesLogger)
    {
        this.logDifferencesLogger = logDifferencesLogger;
    }
}

public interface ILogDifferencesCommand<TModel, TKey>
    where TModel : class, IIdModel<TKey>
{
    List<LogDifference> CalculateDifferences(TModel x, TModel y);

    void LogDifferences(TModel x, TModel y, string tableName, string keyField, string userId, int? clientId);

    void RegisterCustomDisplayNameObserver(WeakReference<ICustomDisplayNameObserver<TModel>> observer);

    void RegisterCustomChangeDateObserver(WeakReference<ICustomChangeDateObserver<TModel>> observer);
}

public interface ILogDifferencesLogger<TKey>
{
    void LogDifferences(string tableName, string keyField, string userId, TKey id, List<LogDifference> differences, int? clientId);
}
```

The reason `TKey` is required is because of the `IIdModel` interface.

Comment: Umm, I think youre a bit overthinking. Just create ILoggerFactory and instantiate your ILogDifferencesCommand<> by some 'Create' method. Seriously, for the name of simplicity - it will be much more readable than raping DI framework. Either way, you use *conventions* to achieve this kind of reflection.

Comment: @eocron I get where you're coming from. However, this allows us to use DI to get the instance in rather than having to add calls throughout numerous constructors. It keeps our classes very succinct and consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that comes to mind:

```
var loggers = new Dictionary<string, ConfiguredInstance>();
loggers.Add("all", c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesAllLogger<>)));
loggers.Add("nlog", c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesNLogLogger<>)));
loggers.Add("database", c.For(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesDatabaseLogger<>)));
foreach (var kv in loggers) {
    // if you still need them named
    // if you only used names for this concrete scenario - you probably don't
    // so can remove it
    kv.Value.Named(kv.Key);
}
c.For(typeof(LogDifferencesCommand<>))
    .Use(typeof(LogDifferencesCommand<>))
    // add explicit instance as dependency
    .Dependencies.Add(typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>), loggers[AppSettingsManager.Get("logDifferences:Target")]);
```

Update. As we've figured out in comments, this doesn't work for your specific case when `LogDifferencesCommand` has multiple type arguments. For some reason (and I think it's a bug) - structure map tries to create closed generic type `ILogDifferencesLogger<>`, but when doing that - passes generic type arguments from `LogDifferencesCommand`. Maybe worth firing an issue at their github. You *can* workaround it like this:

```
public class GenericTypesWorkaroundInstance : Instance
{
    private readonly Instance _target;
    private readonly Func<Type[], Type[]> _chooseTypes;
    public GenericTypesWorkaroundInstance(Instance target, Func<Type[], Type[]> chooseTypes) {
        _target = target;
        _chooseTypes = chooseTypes;
        ReturnedType = _target.ReturnedType;
    }

    public override Instance CloseType(Type[] types) {
        // close type correctly by ignoring wrong type arguments
        return _target.CloseType(_chooseTypes(types));
    }

    public override IDependencySource ToDependencySource(Type pluginType) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override string Description => "Correctly close types over open generic instance";    
    public override Type ReturnedType { get; }
}
```

And then doing

```
commandReg.Dependencies.Add(
    commandReg.Constructor.GetParameters().First(
        p => p.ParameterType.IsGenericType && p.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILogDifferencesLogger<>)).Name, 
        new GenericTypesWorkaroundInstance(
            loggers[AppSettingsManager.Get("logDifferences:Target")],
            // specify which types are correct
            types => types.Skip(1).ToArray()));
```

And it works, but I cannot say that I like it.

Comment: That is a really elegant solution, and exactly what I'm looking for, but right now it's throwing this error `The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition`.  I'm checking that out now to see what I may have done wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can post more complete definition of your classes, because I did test that (with classes and interfaces based on your description) before posting.

Comment: Yeah I think I messed you up - my bad boss - the issue is that `ILogDifferencesCommand` requires two types - `TModel` and `TKey` - so I had to change the code just slightly to build to this `For(typeof(ILogDifferencesCommand<,>))`. That's where the constructor get `TKey` for the `ILogDifferencesLogger`.

Comment: I updated my original question with some of the type definitions in this mix - my apologies - I totally should have included those originally.

Comment: Well, I could have noticed that "," in `ILogDifferencesCommand<,>`. Quite strange it doesn't work in this case and works when `ILogDifferencesCommand` has just one type argument. Cannot understand how it could influence constructor dependency which in both cases is the same (but somehow it does).

Comment: I agree because I had a dynamic solution that worked with `Named` where I provided a value for the `logDifferencesLogger` that then started failing when the class required the `TKey`. Very **frustrating!**

Comment: I've updated with my futher thoughts about this and (ugly) workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The author of StructureMap (me) would strongly advise you try to use conditional registration upfront at application bootstrapping time to select the default logger registrations by checking the configuration value and then just allowing auto-wiring to handle the dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a solution example?  It doesn't have to be complete, but I'm not 100% sure I understand the solution and a small example of that configuration would help a lot.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you're referring to - are you referring to conditional if statements? If so, that won't work because this is a configuration value that's not based on the build type.